# In **Mathematica**, how to compute physical

Tags: physicalconstants-package

I want to calculate the speed of a car:

```
   180 km / 2 hour
    (*  25 m/s *)
```

this is a simple question, but I do not know how to  implement

Comment: Perhaps `Quantity[]` and `UnitConvert[]` can help.

Comment: OK, let me try it.

Comment: You can use CTRL + = to enter your units free form. See the last bullet in the Details section [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InlineFree-formInput.html)

Comment: Please search "unit" in the document. 还有，来把这个读了：http://note.youdao.com/share/?id=abd51087f44c0b6a41ff6022d549dc41&type=note#/

Comment: First contact physics

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the documentation on [`UnitDiscovery`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnitDiscovery.html)
and [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) and [`UnitConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert.html).

A few things that gave me trouble at first were (1) the units are always strings; they are capitalized and they are plural.  For example

```
{Quantity[180, "Kilometers"], 
Quantity[2,"Hours"],
Quantity[6,"Feet"]}
```

(2) When [`PhysicalConstants`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PhysicalConstants/tutorial/PhysicalConstants.html) are entered, they are not plural.  For example,

```
Quantity[5,"ElectronCharge"]
UnitConvert[%,"SIBase"]
```

(3) To find out how to enter a quantity, use the Ctrl= key and the `InputForm` function.  For example:

```
Ctrl= 1 amp   //InputForm
Ctrl= -10 V   //InputForm
Ctrl= 21.1kΩ  //InputForm
Ctrl= 0.53 Å  //InputForm
```

Please see the documentation.  Also, searching this forum for previous questions about Quantity and UnitConvert is highly recommended.

Comment: Note that while most units are plural, there are several exceptions.  For example:  "UkraineSovietRuble" and "AstronomicalUnit".  An absence of pluralization is most commonly seen with currency units.